# Array in cookie, access with pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cookies, pdo

I have an array of id's in a cookie.
When I print the cookie array it prints like this: 
`["39","580"]`. I need to access `id` `39` and `580`.

I have tried everything I need to use this in a query like this:

```
    $queryordenar = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM property 
    WHERE id IN (:list) ORDER BY price ASC");
    $queryordenar->execute(array(
    'list' => $array
     ));
```

Thanks

Comment: The :list won't expand as you expect. You need to split the array using ```explode```, and then build the string needed in your SQL statement before you execute the statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an array as a parameter. You need to explode the array, pass in a ? for every value, and then bind the correct value to each placeholder:

```
$bindPlaceholders = [];
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $bindPlaceholders[] = "?";
}
$bindString = "(".implode(",", $bindPlaceholders).")";
$queryordenar = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM property WHERE id IN ".$bindString." ORDER BY price ASC");
foreach ($array as $i => $val) {
    $queryordenar->bindValue($i + 1, $val); // binding starts at 1
}
$queryordenar->execute();
```

Comment: There must be a ) missing on this line:
$bindString = "(".implode(",", $bindPlaceholders.")";

Comment: That means $array is not really an array. Oh, I see it's JSON encoded. So first decode it: $array = json_decode($array). Then, you will have an array and the $bindString value will be populated correctly.

Comment: I get:
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home…
syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') –
 
The cookie is done like this previously: setcookie("list", json_encode($array) –

Comment: That made the trick thanks @ishegg, full code:
$array = $_COOKIE["list"];
$array = json_decode($array);
$bindPlaceholders = [];
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $bindPlaceholders[] = "?";
}
$bindString = "(".implode(",", $bindPlaceholders).")";
$queryordenar = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM property WHERE id IN ".$bindString." ORDER BY price ASC");
foreach ($array as $i => $val) {
    $queryordenar->bindValue($i + 1, $val); // binding starts at 1
}
$queryordenar->execute();

Comment: Glad I could help.